How to deal with missing chunk offsets in MP4 file despite correct structure?
I have a question regarding an issue I've encountered while working on an MP4 analyzer in VB.NET without third-party libraries. I'm using only the purchased documentation from Iso.org (14496-14:2020 and 14496-15:2022). I've implemented everything as described there. Over the past few months, I've used many test cases (test videos from different sources) to identify as many peculiarities as possible and to test the program. Some peculiarities have already been discovered, but that's not the focus here.
The problem is that a video appears to be structurally sound in terms of its values (dimensions, size, frame count, time scale, etc.), but in reality, it only has 3 values in the ChunkOffset list, even though the video has 103 frames and 103 sample sizes. I can't figure it out. When I open the video with Notepad++, I can see that there's an ‘FS’ before ‘stco’, indicating that the box is only 28 bytes long. However, I can still play the video smoothly with the VLC player.

The purpose of the stco box is to provide information about the offsets between frames with varying sizes (sampleSize), indicating where each frame begins. This information is encoded in the individual chunk offsets read from the stco box. This is an elementary box – it cannot consist of only 3 entries. Therefore, I'm puzzled by this discrepancy. The documentation does not mention this behavior. Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?
I've verified that this problem only occurs with this specific file, which was downloaded from the internet.
Thank you for any insights or suggestions you may have.
The file header:



"...But in reality, it only has 3 values in the ChunkOffset list, even though the video has 103 frames and 103 sample sizes. I can't figure it out."

28 bytes is correct for 3 chunks. See the table at: STCO - Apple Developer.
DATA field          |   BYTES length
==========================================
Size                |   4
Type 'stco'         |   4
Version             |   1
Flags               |   3
Num of entries      |   4
Chunk offset table  |   4 x your 3 entries

There are 16 bytes of STCO header setup before you reach the chunk offsets table. There are 3 table entries, each using 4 bytes, so the chunk offsets table size is 12 bytes.
So the (16 + 12) == 28 explains why you got 28 bytes as total size for STCO. A chunk can hold N-frames, so in that file it seems they spread 103 frames across 3 chunks.
PS:

"The purpose of the stco box is to provide information about the offsets between frames with varying sizes (sampleSize), indicating where each frame begins"

Not correct. STCO is for chunks of frames (audio or video). A video-only or audio-only file can put all frames into 1 chunk. STSZ will tell you the various frame sizes.

First of all, yes, I knew that the ChunkOffset Count number didn't always equal the SampleSize Count, but it was always close (a few off).
I just realized that the problem is different. My decompression algorithm also turns the 3 ChunkOffsets into 103, as well as 103 items in the stsc First_chunks list, Samples_per_chunk list and Sample_description_index list. I just can't read the nalus correctly. There seems to be a bug there.

So, do I have to sum up the sample sizes, until I see the next chunk offset pos?

What do you mean by "decompression algorithm", are you dealing with compressed atoms or something? If all 3 entries for offsets are showing as 103 then you'll have to sum up the sizes. Yes summing up is necessary sometimes with these MPEG media files. Usually summing is for reaching a specific frame number within the chunk but you'll have to do it for the whole file.

PS: Does a hex editor show three "103" numbers as chunk offsets? Anyway to share the header bytes for analysis?

Hi, I think we need to have a conversation or chat somewhere. I'll definitely publish the result here, but first, I want to explain everything, and that won't fit into a comment. However, that will have to wait a few days because my doctor has prescribed bed rest.

@VC.One You should be able to create a "chat" room for this by clicking on the burger menu at the top-right and clicking on the chat link, then it looks like the "create a new room" button towards the bottom-right should go somewhere useful.

@AndrewMorton Thanks for the tip-off, I'm looking into it now. I also saw Discussion which I like the visual formatting better than Chat. I've never tried either until today.

Daniel, Please either start a Chat or Discussion and post the link here and I will respond. Thanks

Hey VC.One, here's the link to the discussion :) https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78453903/discussion-between-vc-one-and-daniel-mp4-chunk-positions-and-nalus-analysis-v

Hey @VC.One, here's the link to the chat because the discussion was closed by Mods. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257636/discussion-between-vc-one-and-daniel
